# Spring Boot: Controller beans are not created

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I have created a simple Spring boot Application with single API, but the API is not exposed to the users.

I am using java version 17.
Spring boot: 3.0.3

Please find my code

**Controller**

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test(){
        return "test";
    }
}
```

**MainApplication**

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**application.properties**

```
server.port=8081
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

As a process of debugging, I have added actuator and hit the APIs /mappings and /beans.
Noticed that my **/test** API is not in the mappings list, and also
There is no bean for my controller **TestController** is found in the beans list.

Comment: what is the url you are trying to hit?

Comment: What is the OS you are running on? Windows? If so you are probably running into https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/34379

Comment: I am trying to hit "/test"

Comment: try adding `logging.level.org.springframework=debug` in applicaiton.properties and restart the application. Then you search for the `TestController` in the output console to see if it shows anything?

Answer (score -4):

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {“com.example.package”}, exclude={Controller.class}), use this in main class

Comment: He wants the controller to be created, the issue is that it isn't.